# override employee time card release method

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

Hello friends I need help:
Here I specify what I am doing:

1.- I am overriding the release method of Employee Timecard, do a validation to get the project's default branch code, and then insert it into the project's transaction screen.

```
public class TimeCardMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<TimeCardMaint>
{
    #region Event Handlers
    public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter a);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate InvokeBase)
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<RegisterEntry>((graph) =>
        {
            graph.RowInserted.AddHandler<PMTran>((sender, e) =>
            {

                EPTimecardDetail detail = PXResult<EPTimecardDetail>.Current;
                if (detail != null)
                {
                    var tran = (PMTran)e.Row;
                    PMProject project = PXSelect<PMProject,
                      Where<PMProject.contractID, Equal<Required<PMProject.contractID>>>>.Select(Base, detail.ProjectID);
                    if (project != null)
                    {
                        tran.BranchID = project.DefaultBranchID;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        return InvokeBase(adapter);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

[image]

Here we see the Transactions screen of the project, make the correct change.

So far everything perfect:
[image]

However, if I check the Journal Transactions screen, it has generated two new entries, it should really only generate a single journal entry as it does by default in acumatica.

[image]

Due to these consequences, it is because I have modified the employee's time card, in the release method, I don't know what is happening:

I need you to tell me what I should do or what I am doing wrong, really I only have to modify the Project Transactions screen and the others should not affect I hope I have been clear..

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the code, the release function for the Project Transactions groups them together by branch.

This is executed at each entry:

```
                Batch newbatch = je.BatchModule.Insert(new Batch
                {
                    Module = doc.Module,
                    Status = BatchStatus.Unposted,
                    Released = true,
                    Hold = false,
                    BranchID = branchID,
                    FinPeriodID = parts[1],
                    CuryID = parts[2],
                    CuryInfoID = info.CuryInfoID,
                    Description = doc.Description
                });
```

As you can see, it adds to the batch of the branch. This would filter out one document for each type, even though it could be separate on the line:

[image]

Since you are having one time card, and then two branches, it would post one time card to one branch, then the other time card to the other branch. If you were to change the line item for each, you would have to override the entire release functions. So based on spending time combing through the project code, and knowing the GL processes, it seems to be operating as intended for acumatica.

Now to your point to bring it into one, I would override the Release function of the PX.Objects.PM.RegisterReleaseProcess graph:

```
    public virtual List<Batch> Release(JournalEntry je, PMRegister doc, out List<PMTask> allocTasks)
```

You would make a copy of the entire function, and then create one batch, and then override the transaction. The document would still be tagged with the employee's primary branch, but each line would then be updated to the proper branch.

NOTE: This would need to be tested thoroughly each update to Acumatica. You would also need to verify from the accounting side that all of the reporting is correct. Some companies may report on the document's branch rather than the transactions, or ignore it and look at the account that it is hitting altogether.

I hope this helps get you to the desired solution!